# Is the following function bijective? I believe not, but need conformation please. (Solved)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $f: \{2, 3, 4, ...\} \rightarrow \{ 2,3,4, ... \}$ such that

$$f(n) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left (\frac{1 + \sqrt 5}{2}\right)^n -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left (\frac{1  - \sqrt 5}{2}\right)^n$$

Is $f$ bijective?

I believe this function is NOT bijective, because f(2) = 1, which is outside of the domain of either set.

Although, I'm really having difficulty grasping this concept and can't find a good explanation. Any help would be great!

Comment: The specific function given you should hopefully recognize if you've been shown it before.  It is the closed form of the fibonacci numbers.  $f(1)=1,f(2)=1,f(3)=2,f(4)=3,f(5)=5,f(6)=8,f(7)=13$ and so on.  You are correct that $f(2)$ is not in fact an element of the codomain and so as written it is *not even a function in the first place!*  If we were to choose to correct that and say that it is a function from $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ to $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ instead, it still isn't bijective.  You could show this a number of ways, e.g. by showing that the function is strictly increasing and skips $4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Can you say if this function is monotone increasing or decreasing? For example, suppose $f$ is monotone increasing. Then since $f(4)=3$ and $f(5)=5$, we know that $4$ is not in the image of $f$!

Side Note Hint: Do you know how to write the Fibonacci numbers explicitly instead of recursively?

Comment: I know this function is increasing, as far as I can tell, and as for Fibonacci, I understand that the next number in the sequence is the sum of the previous numbers. 

I'm not sure how either of that applies though. I'm having a terrible time grasping this concept and I can't really find many examples that are close to this one. They all seem so different, including all of the examples in my textbook.

Comment: Okay, so if you know that it is increasing, just start computing some values. If the function ever skips over a number, then since the function is increasing you know that it can never hit that number!

Comment: AHHHH that makes sense, thanks. I notice after I started plugging it in that it produces the Fibonacci sequence, I guess I missed it because I just started with 2 as the value of n.

Comment: Glad to help! Also, welcome to math StackExchange! Remember to accept one of the answers by clicking the check by the arrows if you figured it out! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your example proves it is not even a function.  You win already.  If we ignore that problem, note that $f(n)$ is monotonic and grows faster than $n$. Again, that is all you need.  Somewhere there will be an $n$ that is not the image of the function.  Note that $f(3)=2, f(4)=3, f(5)=5$ and there is no $n$ such that $f(n)=4$.  This is Binet's formula for the Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: I showed three ways the assertion that it was a bijective function is wrong.  I think the Fibonacci one is the weakest.  If it grows too fast you don't need to know that it is the Fibonacci series.  If I assert that $f(n)=\lfloor n^{1.00001} \rfloor$ is bijective you can prove me wrong by showing an $n$ such that $f(n) \gt n$ because $f(n)$ is increasing so you can never come back and get the missing one.